# Let p be a prime number, show that if p ≡ 1 mod 3, then p ≡ 1 mod 6

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have the following assignment:
Let $p$ be a prime number, show that if $p\equiv_{3}1$, then $p\equiv_{6}1$

I am having trouble making an approach to the solution.I appreciate any help. I can´t make the modulo to change to show the equivalence. I only proved that $p^2=3L+1$, equivalent to $p^2\equiv_{3}1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is likely a dupe but I had no luck finding a good target.

Comment: @BillDubuque I did a quick check myself, but the best I could find was [Is that true that all the prime numbers are of the form $6m \pm 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41623/is-that-true-that-all-the-prime-numbers-are-of-the-form-6m-pm-1), but which I didn't think was quite close enough for me to vote to close this as a duplicate of this other question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ be a prime with $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$. Suppose toward a contradiction that $p\not\equiv 1\pmod 6$. Since $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ we must then have that $p\equiv 4\pmod 6$. But then $p$ is even and since $p$ is prime $p = 2$. But $2\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Why if since ≡1(mod3) we must then have that ≡4(mod6)?

Comment: @FrangoFuentes $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ says $p$ is $1$ more than a multiple of $3$, so it is either $1$ or $4$ than a multiple of $6$. We're assuming $p\not\equiv 1 \pmod 6$, so it must be $4$ more than a multiple of $6$.

Comment: @FrangoFuentes : If you want to spell it out more explicitly to ensure that you're reasoning correctly, you can try all $6$ possibilities for the remainder of $p$ modulo $6$, and see that only $1$ is possible. That is, $p=6k$ or $p=6k+1$ or … or $p=6k+5$. …

Comment: … You can rewrite each of these equations as $p=3(2k)+\text{something}$ or $p=3(2k+1)+\text{something}$ to see what $p$ is modulo $3$, and only $2$ of these will give the correct answer ($1$) to that. You can also rewrite them all as $p=2(3k)+\text{something}$ etc, and only $3$ of them will come out odd (which is required of every prime number besides $2$, as in nbritten's argument). And only $1$ will survive both challenges, which is the $p=6k+1$ possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $ $ it's easy as $\,a,m,n = 1,2,3\,$ below, for $\,p\,$ *any* integer.

**CCRT** $ $ For coprime $\,m,n\!:\,\ p\equiv a\pmod{\!mn}\iff \begin{align}&p\equiv a\!\!\pmod{\!m}\\  &p\equiv a\!\!\pmod{\!n}\end{align}$

since $\, mn\mid p\!-\!a\iff m,n\mid p\!-\!a\,$ by $\,m,n\,$ coprime (so lcm = product, or by Euclid's Lemma)

**Remark** $\ $ This is [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) = Constant case of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem - a ubiquitous result well worth commiting to memory. You can find a handful of complete proofs in the linked answer if the above hint doesn't suffice.

Comment: I like graphical representation of theorems lately.