# Faster primality testing?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, programming, primality-test

I have to make a list of primes, and I found out that all primes are of the form 6n+1 or 6n+5 (however not all numbers of this form are prime). Thus, I use it to find primes more quickly as such:

```
is_prime(n):
   for all i <= sqrt(n)
       if i divides n: return False
   return n >= 2

generate_prime(past_prime):
    // Since we know the past prime is already of the form 6n+1 or 6n+5, we just need to add either 4 or 2 respectively to get to the next candidate prime

    if past_prime mod 6 is 1: past_prime += 4 // Moves from 6n+1 to 6n+5
    else: past_prime += 2 // Moves from 6n+5 to 6n+7->6(n+1)+1

    while(True):
        if(is_prime(past_prime)):
            return past_prime
        if past_prime mod 6 is 1: past_prime += 4 
        else: past_prime += 2
```

What would be the speed of this algorithm (in terms of big O)? How would it compare to other deterministic methods like the sieve Erasthones?

Comment: It's a well-known result and it is widely used. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41623/is-that-true-that-all-the-prime-numbers-are-of-the-form-6m-pm-1

Comment: Sieve methods have an awful complexity in finding large primes. Much better is , for example , the Adleman Pomerance Rumely test , or if you or content with an extremely reliable test with no known counterexample , apply the test in the below answer. In practice , the best approach is to sieve out numbers with small factors of a list or range and to test the remaining candidates.

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly `O(log(n)*sqrt(n))` since the odds of a number being prime are roughly `1/log(n)` and your `isprime` is roughly `O(sqrt(n))`. The main improvement here is to use a much faster `is_prime` function. Instead you can use something like [Baillie-PSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) which has runtime of `O(log(n)^k)` for some fairly small `k`. This optimization will make your code a few orders of magnitude faster for large inputs.