# Coman's Last Conjecture stating that every prime $q \geq 11$ can be written as $3 \cdot (p_1-1) + p_2$, where both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime numbers.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, conjectures, prime-gaps, open-problem, goldbachs-conjecture

Today I was taking a look at Coman's book entitled [Conjectures on Primes and Fermat Pseudoprimes, many based on Smarandache function](https://vixra.org/abs/1411.0153) (starting from the end, as I often do) and his last conjecture, the only one belonging to Part Two, Section 14 (see the above, p. 81), is as follows.

**Coman's Last Conjecture:** Let us denote by $\mathbb{P}$ the set of the prime numbers and assume that $p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{P}-\{2\}$.
If $q \in \mathbb{P}-\{2,3,5,7\}$, then $q = 3 \cdot (p_1 - 1) + p_2$.

**Personal consideration:** My idea is very simple (I've come up with this in a couple of minutes).
Let $p_1 := 3$. It follows that $q = 6 + p_2$ holds for any pairs $(q, p_2)$ having a gap equal to $6$.
Now, a well-known property of primes is that every prime number is of the form $6 \cdot n \pm 1$ (see [proof that all primes above $3$ are congruent to $\{1,5\}\pmod 6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27883/is-it-true-that-all-senary-numbers-ending-in-1-and-5-are-primes)) so that $q = 6 \cdot n \pm 1$ and $p_2 = 6 \cdot m \pm 1$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$.
Thus, we can say that $p_1 := 3 \Rightarrow q = 6 + p_2 \Rightarrow n = m + 1$ if $p_2 \in \mathbb{P} : q-p_2=6$. Otherwise, let $p_1 := 5 \Rightarrow q = 3 \cdot 4 + p_2$ if $p_2 \in \mathbb{P} : q-p_2=2 \cdot 6$, and so forth.
The point here is that, as far as I know, we cannot say that there are infinitely many pairs of primes with a gap of $6$, $12$, or $18$ (etcetera), since these would be some special cases of Polignac's conjecture, which is still unproved for any prime gap as above).

Am I wrong? Is Coman's conjecture implicit in Goldbach's conjecture, by any chance?

P.S.
My first thought is to try to use Chen's (first) Theorem, stating that "every sufficiently large even number (i.e., larger than e^{e^{36}}) can be written as the sum of either two primes, or a prime and a semiprime", since it is trivial to note that $q-3$ is even by construction and $q - 3=3 \cdot p_1 + p_2$ is the sum of $p_2$ and the semiprime $3 \cdot p_1$, the only issue is that $3 \cdot p_1$ is a constrained semprime and not a generic one. Thus, we cannot prove the conjecture for any $q-3 > e^{e^{36}}$.

Comment: Not sure what your point is.  Presumably the conjecture is that, given $q$ as described, we can find two odd primes, $p_1,p_2$, with $q=3(p_1-1)+p_2$.  It does not say that we can fix $p_1$, say, for all $q$.

Comment: For instance, $41=3\times (5-1)+29$  or $97=3\times (7-1)+79$

Comment: Yes, I know. At first, I have fixed $p_1=3$ in order to enlight the corresponding prime gap induced on the pair $(q, p_2)$ (something working like the Sieve of Eratostene for primes), then we should move on $p_1=5$ which would map only the residual primes $q$ such that $q-p_2=2 \cdot 6$, and so forth.

Comment: Ok...still not clear what point you are making.  The obvious first step in testing the conjecture would be to do a deep search for counterexamples.  I can't imagine that existing techniques are strong enough to prove it (if it is true) but maybe a counterexample can be produced.

Comment: My point: although I suspect that the conjecture is true, I think it can be disproven only if Polignac's conjecture would be disproved (and I am pretty confident that it won't ever be disproven)... but I cannot figure out any way to prove it to be true... maybe using G.C., stating that every prime is the sum of two primes and here we have that $q+3:=p_1+p_1+(p_1+p_2)$, could help?

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason to believe that claim, though of course it is possible.  A priori, I don't see why the present conjecture might be true, but each given $p_1$ only occurs finitely often.  Maybe there's some argument to suggest that, but I don't see one in your post.

Comment: I have no certainty about this, just curious to know more. I've spent less than one hour thinking on it, without running any program, so it's just a personal impression, nothing more.

Comment: @Marco Nevertheless , a program would give a first impression whether this conjecture can be true at all. Should it have a small counterexample (which is probably not the case considering that it is a relatively famous conjecture) , we could save much time by avoiding to try to prove it.

Comment: Maybe , it helps to reformulate the conjecture for the sake of a program : "For every prime $q\ge 11$ , there is an odd prime $p$ such that $q-3p+3$ is positive and prime." This is also less confusing than the given formulation with the sets which sounds as we can choose the odd primes and then , for every prime $q\ge 11$ , we have the given equality , which is of course nonsense.

Comment: My idea is to try to use Chen's (first) Theorem, stating that "every sufficiently large even number (i.e., larger than $e^{e^{36}}$) can be written as the sum of either two primes, or a prime and a semiprime", since it is trivial to note that $q-3$ is even by construction and $q - 3=3 \cdot p_1 + p_2$ is the sum of $p_2$ and the semiprime $3 \cdot p_1$, the only issue is that $3 \cdot p_1$ is a constrained semprime and not a generic one. Thus, we cannot prove the conjecture for any $q-3 > e^{e^{36}}$. Any hints?

Comment: @Marco I doubt that we can reduce the problem to Chen's theorem (is this insane huge bound really the best that has been established ?) But we can establish heuristics indicating the truth of the given conjecture.

Comment: @Peter. As far as I know, that huge bound still holds (but I can possibly be wrong). Anyway, I've added my previous comment in the original post and yes, since $3 \cdot p_1$ does not cover the whole set of "semiprimes union primes", this does not prove that the conjecture holds for any $q > e^{e^{36}}$, but it gave me the initial hint that made me becoming to suspect the truthness of the conjecture itself.

Comment: For $11\le q \le 10^{10}$ , there is always such a prime $p\le 797$

Comment: Nice, Peter. Happy to see that we both share the interest for this kind of recreational math open problems. So, let me introduce you a preprint of mine concerning the same kind of problems that I think you will like. Here it is (feel free to contact me if you will find any counterexample to the main conjecture or a perfect cube which is a permutation of 1_2_..._9_10_11...): https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.10163

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140512/discussion-between-peter-and-marco).